# Out of the box functionality for Leads and Campaigns

Tags: leads

Good day all,
I am new to SFDC and wanted to know where I could find information that shows me what is available to my company native and "out of the box" for Leads and Campaigns.  COuld someone please point me in the right direction.  We will be integrating with Eloqua but I wanted to know what SFDC has in place.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend reading up on campaign influence. This is standard Salesforce functionality, and can be incredible useful for marketers. In my experience, however, it can be very confusing to wrap your head around at first glance.

Great blog post here: http://certifiedondemand.com/salesforce-com-certified-administrator/sales-cloud/understanding-salesforce-campaign-influence/

Salesforce documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_influence_intro.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

To quickly get an idea, I'd advice you to watch some of the youtube content. Everything you see there is standard Leads and Campaigns.
E.g.:
Leads:  http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/Sales_Cloud_General/help/Manage_Leads_Opptys_video.jsp
Campaigns: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXVbFKRoZOM

For a deeper dive, you could start with the SF help function:
Leads: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_def.htm&language=en_US
Campaigns: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_def.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

If you purchase Professional Edition or above, you will get access to campaigns.

If you have Campaign functionality, you should use campaign members / responses as often as you have the ability to -- especially if you've spent cash on a specific campaign.  So for example if someone registers for one of your webinars, you should track that as a campaign member response.  If they download an asset, you should track that as a response to another one of your campaigns.

The campaign member history accumulates on leads and carries over to contacts and is indelible.  The campaign response is one of the most durable and useful objects in the entire salesforce.com ecosystem!

Assuming your sales reps create Opportunity Contact Roles, the aforementioned Campaign Influence reports will work.

Salesforce by default will apply the "Last Campaign Response" as the Primary Campaign in the opportunity an opportunity is created is directly by lead convert or directly from a campaign.

If you need more sophisticated way of looking at a more complex campaign consumption environment, you should check out a cheap add-on app like the [Magic Robot Campaign Influence Analyzer & Contact Role Creator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5kDjEAJ)